# Pre-Order traversal of binary tree without peramaters

Tags: c++, recursion, binary-tree

This function gets called by the tree object (root) itself. I need to use recursion to display the pre-order traversal. However, the method I have tried is not working because the roots on the stack get updated on every call for every stack frame.

Here is the main function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Tree.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {

    binaryTree* MyTree = new binaryTree();

    MyTree->insert(100);
    MyTree->insert(25);
    MyTree->insert(11);
    MyTree->insert(2);
    MyTree->insert(87);
    MyTree->insert(50);
    MyTree->insert(35);

    node* tmp = MyTree->search(11);
    cout << "Found " << tmp->value << " located at " << (int)tmp << endl;

    MyTree->Display_preorder();
    MyTree->Display_inorder();
    MyTree->Display_postorder();

    delete MyTree;

    return 1;
}
```

And here is the Pre-Order Traversal function in the Tree class:

```
void binaryTree::Display_preorder()
{
    if (root == NULL) 
        return;
    
    std::cout << root->value << ", ";

    if (root->left != nullptr) {
        root = root->left;
        Display_preorder();
    }

    if (root->right != nullptr) {
        std::cout << root->value << ", ";
        root = root->right;
        Display_preorder();
    }    
}
```

**The output of the current implemented Pre-Order Traversal:**

100, 25, 11, 2, 2

**Expected output:**

100, 25, 11, 2, 87, 50, 35

Comment: Have you been asked not to use parameters? - because that would be the normal way to do it - the parameter being the local root. Without that you will need an explicit stack to keep track of where you are.

Comment: Create a new private function that does the recursion with a node parameter: `void Display_preorder(const node* n) const` and have your `Display_preorder()` function simply call that and pass in the root.  The function could even live on the `node`, I guess.  Note that I've been explicit with the use of `const` which prevents you from doing crazy stuff like modifying your tree's root just to display it.  A traversal should be able to work on a constant tree.

Comment: Yes, it must be done without parameters.

Comment: If none of your recursion is allowed to be parameterized then there's almost no point in using recursion at all.  That said, you don't _need_ to use a parameter if you do it on the node itself...  _i.e._ `root->Display_preorder();` ...  So, the function `node::Display_preorder()` would display itself, then invoke the display function on its left and right, then exit.  Perhaps that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Ended up using Paddys' approach. I suppose the exercise was just poorly designed.